# # Command failed: /Users/arifgohtama/anaconda3/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create .../.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

I am a total beginner in `Kivy` and has been following the crash course tutorial video to learn. Installation and creating app in macOS has been going very well until I have to try to make it into an Android app. It kept get stuck at running `ndk-build v = 1` and told me that -

> Android NDK: WARNING:/Users/arifgohtama/Desktop/AndroidAPK/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/bootstrap_builds/sdl2-python3/jni/application/src/Android.mk:main:
>   non-system libraries in linker flags: -lpython3.7m
>   Android NDK:
>   This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using
>   LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES     Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES
>   instead to list the library dependencies of the

Comment: The text you posted is not an error, and probably doesn't matter (it always appears in p4a builds, it's okay because the environment is set up correctly). Post the full log showing the faliure.

Comment: @inclement is this enough? link: https://pastebin.com/ScW4aEp3.